# how to fill html input tag(TEXT typed) value of a html application from a c# program

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a html application program that works properly fine
I have to run this program from a c# program and fill its html input text tags from my c# program and then press the html button
I've got no idea how to do this
Could you please help me?

Comment: Your question is rather general. What have you got so far?

Comment: Do you want to pass the text box values to code behind(c#)? & do you want to save this values to database?

Comment: I want to fill the value of text boxes from my c# program

Comment: I want to fill the boxes instead of a real person and press the button

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Comment: here is the text boxes in my html application

Comment: <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="ip" onkeyup="checkInput(this)"></input>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, you need to use WebBrowser control and navigate to your site (use `WebBrowser.Navigate()` method). Then (when navigation is completed) use the code to fill the inputs and click the button.

```
var document = yourWebBrowser.Document;

var searchField = document.GetElementById("IdOfTheInputField");
searchField.SetAttribute("value", "TextToWrite");

document.GetElementById("IdOfSubmitButton").InvokeMember("click");
```